# WebBrowser control opening IE under svchost.exe

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, process, webbrowser-control, window.open

I have a web app that needs to be opened from a Windows Forms application.

My current approach is to use a WebBrowser control on the form and execute a JavaScript function (`window.open`) from the WebBrowser control.

This method works fine when I have an IE instance running already. Note that in this case, IE is running under explorer.exe:

[image]

When my application opens and the `window.open` is executed, a new iexplore.exe process is created under explorer.exe.

The issue comes when I run my application without a preexisting IE instance. When I do this, my application opens IE under svchost.exe as shown in this picture.

[image]

If no iexplore.exe processes are running under svchost.exe, the window is opened properly. After I close the IE window opened by my application, the iexplore.exe process is persisted preventing my application from opening any more IE windows. (If I kill the iexplore.exe process under svchost.exe, I am able to open IE from my application again.)

I created a small application to demonstrate the issue. If you create a Windows Forms application with a single form and a single WebBrowser control, and use the following code in your Form1.cs file, you will be able to reproduce the issue I am running into.

**Question: Is there any way to force IE to open under explorer.exe?**

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://google.com");
            this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement head = doc.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            HtmlElement scriptEl = doc.CreateElement("script");

            string jsScript = @"function openApp (urlToOpen) {
                                    window.open(urlToOpen, '_blank');
                                    // do a couple other things
                                }";

            scriptEl.SetAttribute("text", jsScript);
            head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

            webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("openApp", new object[] { "http://google.com" });
        }
    }
}
```